# In my JAVA program , I have three sockets, how many threads i will need to handle that?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I've some sockets ( it's could be considered as blocking) so try to figure out how many threads do I need. Found an old time question:

> In my JAVA program , I have three sockets, how many threads i will
>   need to handle that?

But never found any answers... Actually it's more interesting question can be followed: is forkjoinpool useful in such programs?

Comment: "How many threads do I need"? Using polling, just one. But typically you need a thread to listen for input on every socket. "is forkjoinpool..." maybe I don't understand forkjoinpool, but how would forking or joining be useful here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So sockets are just communication streams. They don't require threads.

If you're trying to consume the responses from multiple sockets in parallel, you could spawn one thread per socket. That is perhaps the easiest approach.

Alternatively, one can use the NIO framework to operate on multiple channels within the same thread.

NIO: https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-2-async-channels